# Shortcut for login to remote computer via SSH

Tags: ssh

I want to shorten my SSH login from my Mac computer to remote computer. Currently, I log in with

```
ssh username@remote.anu.edu.au.
```

I tried to replace the command using a short name in the `cshrc` file, but it did not work. How can I log in to the remote computer without having to type the full command above?

Answer (score 9):

You can add a `config` file (no file extension) to your `.ssh` folder with the following entry:

```
Host x
HostName example.com
User me
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
```

Now, you can log in to `example.com` with the username `me` and  private key `key` with the following command:

```
ssh x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!!!This works but need to password . would you please inform me how can make it password free?

Comment: Oh. You did not mention using a password, so I assumed you used a key. It's a bit more difficult to pass a plain-text password with SSH. This question on AskUbuntu has a couple of solutions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87956/can-you-set-passwords-in-ssh-config-to-allow-automatic-login

Comment: Why don't you set up public-key authentication? It's easier and more secure.

Comment: why hasn't this answer been selected yet?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have it "password free", you can use PublicKey authentification.
It is one of the few concepts that is more secure and also easier.

All you need to do is create a keypair on the client and send the publickey to the server.

Create the keypair: (you should use a strong passphrase)

> ssh-keygen -t rsa

Send your new created publickey to the server:

> ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server

Now you should be able to login without a password.
If not, make shure to configure your ssh server like this:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting an alias in your shell's profile?

```
alias sshzzz='username@remote.anu.edu.au.'
```

Then you can just type `sshzzz` and then put your password in.